# Formula or algorithm that calculates the number of agents needed for a multi-skilled call center environment

Tags: python

I found some formula or algorithm to calculate multi-skilled personnel for a call center but there doesn't seem to be any positive results

I've tried reading a lot of documentation but it doesn't seem to be able to help me realize a multi-skilled call center simulation model in Python. The knowledge I read from math reports far exceeds my current abilities. I am looking for a simple and optimal formula or simulation model to calculate the number of agents needed based on workload, service target call processing time and awt.

I need an algorithm that can run simulations and produce the number of agents needed for this multi-skilled environment.

Can anyone help me. Thanks?

Comment: Hello, currently your question does not provide sufficient details to be answered correctly. Please add more details and check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Queueing theory, but you won't like the answer it gives you, which is that the optimum balance between response time and resource utilization is 0.7 of the latter.